# Form with PHPMailer

Tags: php, arrays, forms, email

I'm trying to make a form that attach a file.
I followed a tutorial, and it's showing this three errors.
If someone can help me and explain it, i will really greatfull

ps: if i send the email without an attachment file, the mail doesn't arrive in the mailbox.

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/deneuve/index.php on line 34
>
> Undefined index: attachment in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/deneuve/index.php on line 40
>
> Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/deneuve/index.php on line 40

```
<?php


    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    session_start();


    $msg = "";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        //require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

        function sendEmail($to, $from, $fromName, $body, $attachment){
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
            $mail->addAdress($to);
            $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
            $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form - Email';
            $mail->Body = $body;
            $mail->isHTML(false);

            return $mail-> send();
        }

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $file = $_POST['attachment'];
        $file = "attachment/" . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_FILES);


        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $file)){
            if(sendEmail('******@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $file)){
                $msg = 'email sent ! :D';}
                else {$msg = 'email failed ! :(';}
        } else{ 
            $msg = "<p style='color:white;'>please check your attachment</p>";
        }

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleform.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content-form">

        <form action="index.php" method="POST" entype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Send us a message" required></textarea>
            <input type="file" name="attachment">
            <button type="submit" value="Enviar Datos" name="submit">SUBMIT !</button>

        </form>

        <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one thing, you have a typo in this word `entype`. It's missing the "c" for it; `enctype`.

Comment: Glad to have helped.